# CSS and form autofil background image

Tags: css, forms, haml, autofill

I have a form that in the input I have an icon in the left part using background with position left.

The design is working perfectly but I see in two of the inputs that automatically appeared my e-mail and my password so my background disappeared.

I have tried using input:-webkit-autofill, input:-webkit-autofill, :focus and input autocomplete="off" but nothing changed.

So I only have the problem when I enter in the page for the first time but if I delete the autofill text I see the background correctly.

So, how can I put the "background" image icon to appear always anyway if there is autofill or not?

This is the haml:

```
= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true, class: "email", placeholder: "Email", autocomplete: "off"
= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "off", class: "password", placeholder: "#{t'common.password'}"
```

And the CSS:

```
input.email {background: $crema url("/assets/profile_mail.png") left no-repeat; background-size: 40px 40px;}      
input.password {background: $crema url("/assets/profile_password.png") left no-repeat; background-size: 40px 40px;}
input.email:focus {background: $crema url("/assets/profile_mail.png") left no-repeat; background-size: 40px 40px;}   
input.password:focus {background: $crema url("/assets/profile_password.png") left no-repeat; background-size: 40px 40px;}
input.email:-webkit-autofill:focus {background: $crema url("/assets/profile_mail.png") left no-repeat; background-size: 40px 40px;}
input.password:-webkit-autofill:focus {background: $crema url("/assets/profile_password.png") left no-repeat; background-size: 40px 40px;}
```

And this is how I see my form:
[image: autofill]

[image: normal]

Comment: `<form autocomplete="off"> </form>`

Comment: Ok, but how can I put the autocomplete inside the haml tag: = form_for (resource, as: resource_name, url: session_path(resource_name)) do |f|? Thank you

Comment: I posted the answer below. I haven't worked with the `haml` very much that's why couldn't make exact code. You'll have to adapt it with your code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`<% form_for :form_name, @form_name, :html => {:autocomplete => "off"} do |f|%>
...
<% end %>`